# VS Code Syntax issues developing a Telegram bot with node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, telegram

Beginner Alert:
I am currently following an online Course and have a discrepancy with my syntax.
I am using VS Code editor and when I need to concatenate a variable and string the sample code syntax is:  'String ${string}'

If I use this the code is just a text.

If I use the following code: ' String: ' + (string)  it seems to work but I am running into problems when I need to add tags and Html(replywithHTML function error)

I am struggling to find a solution to set my editor to comply with what seems to be the standard node.js syntax. I have set the language to JavaScript. Perhaps it's to do with my JSON.Settings??

Any pointers would be appreciated
Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, use Backticks and not single quotes....

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals